# Unable to get Response in retrofit in call.enque()

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2, shopify-app

I am paring `CollectionListing` Api from Shopify and I need to pass `'collecton_listing_id'` as parameter in `url`. I am passing the id but unable to get response in Callback.

**Note:** I have tested the api with parameters in Postman and works fine.

Here is my implementation.

**ProductActivity.java**

```
 private void processProductIds() {

    apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<Integer>> call = apiInterface.getProductIds(key, id);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Integer>> call, Response<List<Integer>> response) {
            String s = String.valueOf(response.body());
            Log.d("S", "onResponse:" + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Integer>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

**ApiInterface.java**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET("collection_listings/{collection_listing_id}/product_ids.json")
Call<List<Integer>> getProductIds(@Header("Authorization") String accessToken, @Path("collection_listing_id") long id);

}
```

**Model Class**

```
public class IdExample {

@SerializedName("product_ids")
@Expose
private List<Integer> productIds = null;

public List<Integer> getProductIds() {
    return productIds;
}

public void setProductIds(List<Integer> productIds) {
    this.productIds = productIds;
 }
}
```

**JSON Response**

```
{
"product_ids": [
    1331092619350,
    1331125551190,
    1331126599766,
    1331121651798
  ]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do you  mean by "unable to get response"? the `onResponse` callback doesn't get called at all? or it gets called but the response is empty?

Comment: @y.allam unable to get response in Callback. The api works fine when tested in postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the return type of `getProductIds` from `Call<List<Integer>>` to `Call<IdExample>`

EDIT: (as discussed in the comments)

You should also change `List<Integer> productIds` to `List<Long> productIds`

Comment: I tried...its not working. Infact, I implemented this at the first place.

Comment: This is the message I am getting in onFailure() in log 'Error Failure: onFailure:java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 1331092619350 at line 1 column 30 path $.product_ids[0]'

Comment: Integer is a 32 bit number, with a maximum value of 2147483647. You should use Long instead

Comment: Yeah exactly got the issue. I will make the changes and try.

Comment: Well, this shows why you should show your research in questions and why you should always consider error branches in code.

Comment: No worries, just remember to log as much as possible when you have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call API using,

```
mAPIService.functionpost("url/"+id).enqueue(new Callback<List<IdExample>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<IdExample>> call, Response<List<IdExample>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (constantsVariables.debug) {
                    Log.i(constantsVariables.TAG, "/****************************/" + response.raw());

                }                 
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<IdExample>> call, @NonNull Throwable tr) {
            Log.d("TEST  Inside fail if", Log.getStackTraceString(tr));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
private void processProductIds() {

apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

Call<IdExample> call = apiInterface.getProductIds(key, id);

call.enqueue(new Callback<IdExample>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<IdExample> call, Response<IdExample> response) {
        String s = String.valueOf(response.body().getProductIds());
        Log.d("S", "onResponse:" + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<IdExample> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
}
```

Then change api interface like this

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("collection_listings/{collection_listing_id}/product_ids.json")
Call<IdExample> getProductIds(@Header("Authorization") String 
accessToken, @Path("collection_listing_id") long id);
}
```